# virtual box on Mac

Tags: virtualbox, macbook-pro

I operate on a i9 16gb platform, utilizing ubuntu   vbox for development but I am encountering technical difficulties with performance. any recommendations on Vbox settings to improve compatiably with my hardware

Comment: Try a trial machine of Ubuntu built inside VMware Fusion for Mac.

Comment: I'd recommend not using VBox. Parallels is 'fastest' but not free. VMWare is next best & has a free for home use version.

Comment: Thanks John, Tetsujin